# Remap structure parent object base on child array data and length object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, arraylist, remap

I am trying remap structure data parent base on child array data and length. It's possible to do? Structure array it's good or i need change array object from backend?

There is no id in child arrays.

**This is what i have done**

```
this.arrays = [
  {
    id: '1',
    idbid: '0000000001618',
    name: 'ebi',
    rate: '400',
    bid: [
      {
        bid: 10000,
        date: '2022/12/12',
        value: 5000,
      },
      {
        bid: 10000,
        date: '2022/12/14',
        value: 8100,
      },
      {
        bid: 15000,
        date: '2022/12/15',
        value: 8100,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    idbid: '0000000001618',
    name: 'bio',
    rate: '100',
    bid: [
      {
        bid: 8000,
        date: '2022/12/13',
        value: 8000,
      },
    ],
  },
];

// merge all item bid in child array
let allVal: any = [];
allVal = allVal.concat(this.arrays.map((data) => data.bid).flat());
console.log(allVal);

// get unique bid
var uniqueData = [];
allVal.forEach((item) => {
  let count = uniqueData.filter((x) => x.value == item.value).length;

  if (count == 0) {
    uniqueData.push(item);
  }
});
console.log(uniqueData);

// find and merge into parent array
const newArrays = uniqueData.map((obj) => {
  return this.arrays.find((data) =>
    data.bid.some((val) => val.value == obj.value)
  );
});
console.log(newArrays);

// remap structure custom arrays of parent
const remapArrays = newArrays.map((obj, index) => {
  return {
    id: index + 1,
    idbid: obj.idbid,
    name: obj.name,
    rate: obj.rate,
    bid: obj.bid[index]?.bid,
    date: obj.bid[index]?.date,
    value: obj.bid[index]?.value,
  };
});
console.log(remapArrays);
```

**but the result is like this**

```
[
  {
    id: '1',
    idbid: '0000000001618',
    name: 'ebi',
    rate: '400',
    bid: 10000,
    date: '2022/12/12',
    value: 5000,
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    idbid: '0000000001618',
    name: 'bio',
    rate: '100',
    bid: 10000,
    date: '2022/12/13',
    value: 8100,
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    idbid: '0000000001618',
    name: 'ebi',
    rate: '400',
    bid: undefined,
    date: undefined,
    value: undefined,
  },
];
```

**and here is what expected output**

```
// output final that exptected
this.customArrays = [
  {
    id: '1',
    idbid: '0000000001618',
    name: 'ebi',
    rate: '400',
    bid: 10000,
    date: '2022/12/12',
    value: 5000,
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    idbid: '0000000001618',
    name: 'bio',
    rate: '100',
    bid: 8000,
    date: '2022/12/13',
    value: 8000,
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    idbid: '0000000001618',
    name: 'ebi',
    rate: '400',
    bid: 15000,
    date: '2022/12/15',
    value: 8100,
  },
];
```

Here is link for test [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ypje7e?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Where does ID '3' come from?

Comment: ID 3 come from by arrays length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things that should be defined more clearly in the question:

- Do we expect the value of `"idbid"` to be the same across all  elements of the original array?
- Should the resulting array have the first date of each unique bid?

In my answer, I'll be assuming that the answer is "yes" to both.

- In the beginning, when merging all child arrays:

```
allVal.concat(this.arrays.map((data) => data.bid).flat());
```

We're losing the values that are unique to each parent element: for example, the value of `"rate"` is `"400"` for the first parent element and `"100"` for the second. So before flattening, we need to map each of the bid arrays, so each child element includes the data from the parent element:

```
// merge all item bids in child arrays
const allVal = this.arrays
  .map((dataWithBids) => {
    const { id, idbid, name, rate, bid: bidArr } = dataWithBids;
    // add data from the parent element to each bid
    return bidArr.map((bidData) => ({
      idbid,
      name,
      rate,
      ...bidData,
    }));
  })
  .flat();
```

In the following step, getting only unique values can be done the same way as you did, or using the array [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
// get unique bids
const uniqueData = [];
allVal.forEach((item) => {
  const exists = uniqueData.some((x) => x.value == item.value);

  if (!exists) {
    uniqueData.push(item);
  }
});
```

At this point we have the correct values, and we need to order them by date and add ids:

```
const sorted = uniqueData
  // sort by date
  .sort(
    (bidData1, bidData2) =>
      Date.parse(bidData1.date) - Date.parse(bidData2.date)
  )
  // add ids
  .map((bidData, index) => ({
    ...bidData,
    id: index + 1 // or (index + 1).toString(),
  }));
```

The result of the above `sorted` array matches the expected output.

Comment: Wow thank you  @Lev, its working now.
I am missing about maping each data when flattenning.
Yes idbid only information value like name
For unique data i want filter by last date if there more one data.
Like expected final ouput the date must be 2022/12/12, 2022/12/13, 2022/12/15